# Catching Firebase Errors in a Bootstrap-Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, authentication, firebase, error-handling

I just finished my own Login-Signup-App with Angular 2 and Firebase, but i have some problems with the "correct" Error-Handling
 My Angular 2 App Structure looks like:

```
|   app.component.css
|   app.component.html
|   app.component.ts
|   app.module.ts
|   app.routing.ts
|   index.ts
|   
+---errors
|       error.component.html
|       error.component.ts
|       error.model.ts
|       error.service.ts
|       
+---protected
|       protected.component.ts
|       protected.guard.ts
|       
+---shared
|       auth.service.ts
|       header.component.ts
|       index.ts
|       user.interface.ts
|       
\---unprotected
        signin.component.ts
        signup.component.ts
```

My whole App works fine, but i now want to catch the FirebaseErrors and show it in a Bootstrap Modal.
I've created an errorService, an errorModel and a errorComponent.  I tried following:

First I defined an Error class in my <kbd>error.model.ts</kbd>

```
export class Error {
    constructor(public title: string, public message: string) {}
}
```

Then i've set up my <kbd>error.component.ts</kbd>

```
export class ErrorComponent implements OnInit{
    error: Error;
    display = 'none';

    constructor(private errorService: ErrorService) {}

    onErrorHandled() {
        this.display = 'none';
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.errorService.errorOccurred.subscribe(
            (error: Error) => {
                this.error = error;
                this.display = 'block';
            }
        );
    }
}
```

with the <kbd>error.component.html</kbd>

```
<div class="backdrop" [ngStyle]="{'display': display}"></div>
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" [ngStyle]="{'display': display}">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="onErrorHandled()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">{{ error?.title }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>{{ error?.message }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="onErrorHandled()">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Now when i want to catch the errors in <kbd>auth.service.ts</kbd>

```
declare var firebase: any;

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    constructor(private router: Router, private errorService: ErrorService) {}

    signupUser(user:User) {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
          .catch(function (error) {
              this.errorService.handleError(error.json());
              return Observable.throw(error.json());
          });
    }
    signinUser(user:User) {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
          .catch(function (error) {
              this.errorService.handleError(error.json());
              return Observable.throw(error.json());
          });
    }
}
```

the console throws these errors:

[image: errors_chrome_console]

I think something is wrong with these two lines:

```
this.errorService.handleError(error.json());
return Observable.throw(error.json());
```

because

```
console.log(error)
```

throws no error it just logs the error in the console.

I've also tried this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39428669/5930557) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth):

```
.catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;
  // ...
}
```

but still no luck.

**I actually want to show this error log from the console:**

```
{code: "auth/email-already-in-use", message: "The email address is already in use by another account."}
```

**to a normal Bootstrap-Modal**

**What am I doing wrong ? or what do i missunderstand ?**

Comment: Have you tried https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal ? It allows you to easily open modals from a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all in your `auth.service.ts` you lose context in your catch function and that's why you get that error. You can solve this by using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
declare var firebase: any;

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    constructor(private router: Router, private errorService: ErrorService) {}

    signupUser(user:User) {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
          .catch((error) => {
              this.errorService.handleError(error.json());
              return Observable.throw(error.json());
          });
    }
    signinUser(user:User) {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
          .catch((error) => {
              this.errorService.handleError(error.json());
              return Observable.throw(error.json());
          });
    }
}
```

Now when catching and error your method from the `errorService` will get called. I don't how your error service is implemented but one approach is to set up a Subject property like in this example:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorService{
    public errorOccurred: Subject<Error>;

    constructor(){
        this.errorOccurred = new BehaviorSubject<Error>(null);
    }

    handleError(error) {
        this.errorOccurred.next(error); //pass next value to subject
    }

}
```

With this setup you will be able to get now errors into you error component:

```
export class ErrorComponent implements OnInit{
    error: Error;
    display = 'none';

    constructor(private errorService: ErrorService) {}

    onErrorHandled() {
        this.display = 'none';
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.errorService.errorOccurred.subscribe(
            (error: Error) => {
                if (error !== null) {
                    this.error = error;
                    this.display = 'block';
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

The only downside with this approach is that you need to keep the error component in your template. A solution for this would be to setup a component factory and inject the modal into your template only when and error occurs. I can setup a plnkr if you need that:)

Comment: thanks for your answer:) it would be very nice if i can see a working code example on plnkr :) thanks anyways for your time

Comment: it finally worked. thanks for the detailed explanation :) i had to change `this.errorService.handleError(error.json());` to `this.errorService.handleError(error);` and it worked